# How to limit extensions to upload files? Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a code:

```
<?=Html::activeHiddenInput($model, $attribute, $inputParams); ?>
<?=Html::fileInput($id, null, ['id' => $id, 'style' => 'display: none']); ?>
```

I need limit extensions to upload file in form, for example:

```
True: jpeg, png, jpg
False: *
```

How can I do this in Yii2?

Comment: http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/yii-validators-filevalidator.html#$extensions-detail

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-file-upload.md#mime-type

it is clearly stated on above link. Don't know why you deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model's rules,

```
[['file'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'gif, jpg'],
```

More at http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/yii-validators-filevalidator.html

Comment: When am using  'types' => 'jpg',display the Error #256

Comment: @NitheesBavesh..Kindly find the updated answer,The previous one was for alpha version of yii2